# How to upgrade Lumia 625 from 3G to 4G

Tags: cellular-data, nokia-lumia-625

I have a Nokia 625 handset with 3G. Where and How can I firmware update it from 3G to 4G?

Comment: As far as I know, the 625 is already 4G-capable. Further, I don't think any Lumia phones can be upgraded in such a manner. What makes you think the Lumia 625 needs to be upgraded, and that such an upgrade exists?